# Overlapped text - begingroup+usepackage{wrapfig} and usepackga{geometry}

Tags: packages, geometry, wrapfigure, overlap

I noticed that if I use begingroup+usepackage{wrapfig} and usepackga{geometry} I got overlapped text, instead if I use only begingroup+usepackage{wrapfig} the text is ok (see figures below please).

How can I overcome this problem by using begingroup+usepackage{wrapfig} and usepackga{geometry}? Is there a way to disable the geometry package only when I use begingroup+wrapfig?

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            right=1cm,
            bottom=1.25cm,
            bindingoffset=0.5cm,
            marginparwidth=15mm
            ]{geometry}




\title{titolo}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{fig}
\caption{Effettore finale (o braccio meccatronico.}
\end{wrapfigure}
L'effettore finale (o braccio meccatronico) è costituito da cinque parti (fig. 1.13):
\begin{enumerate}
\item i meccanismi;
\item i sensori;
\item il sistema di controllo;
\item gli attuatori;
\item il sistema di gestione dell'energia.
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

In fig. 1.14 sono riportati, relativamente ad un braccio meccatronico, i tipi di meccanismi/progettazione dell'architettura, i tipi di sensori e la loro integrazione, i tipi di controllo:
\begin{enumerate}
\item i meccanismi/progettazione dell'architettura si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item meccanismi non ad alta reversibilità (o Non-Back-Drivable Mechanisms, o Non-BackDrivable Mechanisms) NBDMs;
\item meccanismi adattabili;
\item meccanismi che permettono diversi schemi di afferraggio e quindi di manipolazione;
\end{enumerate}
\item i sensori e la loro integrazione si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item sensori controllati automaticamente a basso livello;
\item sensori che forniscono una retroazione;
\end{enumerate}
\item gli algoritmi di controllo si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item algoritmi di controllo che eseguo cicli automaticamente;
\item algoritmi di controllo che comunicano con l'interfaccia uomo-macchina.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }
\usepackage{float}



\title{titolo}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{fig}
\caption{Effettore finale (o braccio meccatronico.}
\end{wrapfigure}
L'effettore finale (o braccio meccatronico) è costituito da cinque parti (fig. 1.13):
\begin{enumerate}
\item i meccanismi;
\item i sensori;
\item il sistema di controllo;
\item gli attuatori;
\item il sistema di gestione dell'energia.
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup

In fig. 1.14 sono riportati, relativamente ad un braccio meccatronico, i tipi di meccanismi/progettazione dell'architettura, i tipi di sensori e la loro integrazione, i tipi di controllo:
\begin{enumerate}
\item i meccanismi/progettazione dell'architettura si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item meccanismi non ad alta reversibilità (o Non-Back-Drivable Mechanisms, o Non-BackDrivable Mechanisms) NBDMs;
\item meccanismi adattabili;
\item meccanismi che permettono diversi schemi di afferraggio e quindi di manipolazione;
\end{enumerate}
\item i sensori e la loro integrazione si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item sensori controllati automaticamente a basso livello;
\item sensori che forniscono una retroazione;
\end{enumerate}
\item gli algoritmi di controllo si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item algoritmi di controllo che eseguo cicli automaticamente;
\item algoritmi di controllo che comunicano con l'interfaccia uomo-macchina.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT: I need to leave more space between the figure and the left text:

[image]

```
\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}% not needed
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-4.1cm}% left column NOTARE che c'è 7 cm come in \includegraphics[width=7cm]
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=3.8cm]{fig1.26}
\caption{Elettrodo Ottobock con filtro integrato.}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
Gli elettrodi che useremo nel progetto sono della Ottobock (fig. 1.26) i quali hanno già un filtro di serie al loro interno per cui il segnale EMG in uscita dagli elettrodi è già filtrato.

In genere il controllo che si fa per aprire/chiudere la mano \ul{potrebbe} essere il seguente (si intuisce dai segni + e - in fig. 1.25):
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*.]
\item se l'attività elettrica dei muscoli flessori del polso è maggiore dell'attività elettrica dei muscoli estensori del polso, diciamo alla protesi di mano di chiudersi;
\item se l'attività elettrica dei muscoli estensori del polso è maggiore dell'attività elettrica dei muscoli flessori del polso, diciamo alla protesi di mano di aprirsi;
\end{enumerate}
\item una scheda elettronica alla quale vengono passati i segnali EMG acquisiti dagli elettrodi;
\item una batteria;
\item una mano;
\end{paracol}
\endgroup
```

Comment: wrapfigure explicitly documents that it does not work to wrap a latex list. I don't think the geometry package here is involved other that the exact effect of wrapping naturally depends on the width of the text block that you happen to have set using that package.

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle the problem is that, if I remove the geometry package, it works. Are you saying that the problem is this set of parameters? left=1.5cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            right=1cm,
            bottom=1.25cm,
            bindingoffset=0.5cm,
            marginparwidth=15mm

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried also \userpackage{geometry} without any parameter and the text is still overlapped.

Comment: well yes as I say, wrapfig does not support lists it may accidentally sort of half work at some text widths but not with any reliable rule, and using the begingroup group makes it even harder to support wrapfig

Comment: that said you may be able to use the optional argument to force wrapfig yo leave more lines, to avoid the over-printing. Try to make an xample using `example-image` as the inage as that is available for tests so people would be able to run your example and test answers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried with example-image and the text/figure is overlapped both when I use and when I don't use the geometry package

Comment: and if you say `\begin{wrapfigure}[20]` (or whatever number works)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Overleaf compiles the file but the text is overlapped, instead Texmaker gives me an error

Comment: Why don't you just use minipge or paracol?  Admittedly they don't actually wrap the text, but the enumitem package allows you to stop and restart enumerate if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows a paracol solution.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,
            top=1.25cm,
            right=1cm,
            bottom=1.25cm,
            bindingoffset=0.5cm,
            marginparwidth=15mm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*

\title{titolo}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}% not needed
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}%
\setcolumnwidth{\dimexpr \textwidth-\columnsep-6cm}% left column
\begin{paracol}{2}
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
\caption{Effettore finale (o braccio meccatronico.}
\end{figure}
\switchcolumn
L'effettore finale (o braccio meccatronico) è costituito da cinque parti (fig. 1.13):
\begin{enumerate}
\item i meccanismi;
\item i sensori;
\item il sistema di controllo;
\item gli attuatori;
\item il sistema di gestione dell'energia.
\end{enumerate}
\end{paracol}
\endgroup

In fig. 1.14 sono riportati, relativamente ad un braccio meccatronico, i tipi di meccanismi/progettazione dell'architettura, i tipi di sensori e la loro integrazione, i tipi di controllo:
\begin{enumerate}
\item i meccanismi/progettazione dell'architettura si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item meccanismi non ad alta reversibilità (o Non-Back-Drivable Mechanisms, o Non-BackDrivable Mechanisms) NBDMs;
\item meccanismi adattabili;
\item meccanismi che permettono diversi schemi di afferraggio e quindi di manipolazione;
\end{enumerate}
\item i sensori e la loro integrazione si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item sensori controllati automaticamente a basso livello;
\item sensori che forniscono una retroazione;
\end{enumerate}
\item gli algoritmi di controllo si suddividono in:
\begin{enumerate}
\item algoritmi di controllo che eseguo cicli automaticamente;
\item algoritmi di controllo che comunicano con l'interfaccia uomo-macchina.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @JohnKormylo thank you very much for your solution. I tried it in Overleaf and I got also lines around the pages. I prefer to avoid these lines.

Comment: Sorry, I added the `showframe` option to geometry to check the alignment.  I removed it now.

Comment: perfect solution.

Comment: I noticed that the successive figure has the same number of the one inside the above code. I fixed the number by modifing the counter: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640983/non-integer-number-in-setcounter-report-document-setcounterfigure1-14

Comment: Sigh!  I keep forgetting to add `\globalcounter*`.

Comment: thank you a lot.

Comment: Hi @JohnKormylo can you take a look to my edit please?

Comment: Okay, you allocated 4.1cm and only used 3.8cm, but left justified.  Using `\centering` or `\raggedleft` or `\hfill`  will help with the image (but not the caption).  If you really want more space, don't set `\columnsep=0pt`.