# Non integer number in setcounter (report document): \setcounter{figure}{1.14}

Tags: counters, renewcommand, setcounter

I'm wondering how to write a non integer number inside the setcounter command. I'm writing a report so the numbers of the figures are not 1, 2, 3, but 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 (in chapter 1).

I tried the command `\setcounter{figure}{1.14}`, but it seems that LaTeX cannot manage it because the number is not an integer. How can I overcome this problem?

After setcounter I used the command `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}` which is defined as `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}`.

Comment: Do `\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}`

Comment: Hello @UlrikeFischer when I use \setcounter{figure}{1.14}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}} I get the same error. I cannot remove \setcounter{figure}{1.14} otherwise I have two figures with the same number.

Comment: no the counter value for figure is always an integer (14) then you print it with `\thefigure` using a prefix of the section counter, as Ulrike showed

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LaTeX, the *value* of a counter -- say, `mycounter` -- has to be an integer. The way this counter is *typeset* is governed by the macro `\themycounter`. This macro can contain information both about the counter's numeric respresentation -- by default, one can choose between arabic numerals (`1`, `2`, etc), uppercase and lowercase Roman numerals (`I`, `II`, etc), and uppercase and lowercase alphabetic letters (`a`, `b`, etc.) -- and about whether this counter should be prefixed by some other item, such as a chapter number.

Here's a practical, though slightly contrived, example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

% reset the 'figure' counter each time 'chapter' counter is changed:
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter} % (that's actually the default)

% going slightly overbord:
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{chapter}.\alph{figure}} 

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{5}
\setcounter{figure}{14}

Numeric value of \texttt{chapter} counter: \arabic{chapter}

Numeric value of \texttt{figure} counter: \arabic{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht] \caption{AAA} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[hh] \caption{BBB} \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[hh] \caption{CCC} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```